# Error when trying to install Flutter on Raspberry pi

Tags: flutter, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to set up Flutter on Raspberry pi but I am stuck. I have done the following.

1) Installed a clean Raspbian Buster Lite.

2) Opened a SSH terminal.

3) Followed this instruction to install Flutter https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux

4) Replaced Dart with this ARM version  https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive

5) Trying to run flutter doctor gives following error:

```
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8)    
✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
    See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information
    On Debian/Ubuntu/Mint: sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
    On Fedora: dnf install libstdc++.i686
    On Arch: pacman -S lib32-gcc-libs
```

6) Stuck,,, I've tried to install :

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

but get a error that "lib32stdc++6" is missing. I've googled a lot but have not find any solution.

Can anyone help?